# Using NLP in already analysed text,

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I have serveral text files.

These files has been analysed through some analytical tool and provided main features

There each feature extracted has one repetition

I know to use predictive modeling in NLP using word2vec, Bag-of-words, Glove, etc.

these method depend on the word repetition

**Example**

```
Text 1 : in Melbourne Supermarket the month of January customers bought more of beef minced meat, Milk law fat 2 liters. also customers were buying cream cheese 250 grams. there was high demand on unsalted butter 200 gram ...

Text 2 : things were a bit different this month for sydney Supermarket customers bought more of orange juice 1 ltr, apple juice 1 ltr and mango juice 1 lts, also Milk law fat 2 liters was on high demand. from confectionary kitkat box 12 pack and Snickers 12 pack were hogh in demand...
```

**The analytics tool gives me these results**

```
Text1 Analysis : Product 3038, Product 6783, Product 5799, , Product 4836, , Product 4882
Text2 Analysis : Product 9398, Product 9391, Product 8349, , Product 8118, , Product 6783
```

and the predictive results are

**Products recommended to be promoted**

```
Text 1 : Recommend Chedder cheese 200 gram, chicken breast 1kg
Text 2 : Recommend Chocolate Milk 1 ltr, Smoothy Apple and Mango 1 ltr.
```

So how can I approach this problem?

Shall I use word2vec, Bag-of-words, Glove?